# Python tkinter Listbox widget: unicode text with ' char get jumbled

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter, listbox, tk-toolkit

Using python 2.7 and Tkinter
I have a Listbox widget and a Text widget showing the same text.
In the Text widget everything looks correct. But in the Listbox the font is different and where there are ' chars the text gets to be jumbled.

How can the Listbox text be shown properly ?

Here's a screenshot of the Text widget:
[image: Text widget screenshot]
And Here's one for the Listbox widget:
[image: Listbox widget screenshot]

The listbox creation code is:

```
self.r_list = Listbox(self.frame, selectmode='multiple', exportselection=0)
for item in self.all:
    self.r_list.insert(END, item)
```

and the text creation code is:

```
self.r_text = Text(self.frame)
self.r_text.insert(END, "\n".join(self.all))
self.r_text.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Where the self.all var is:

```
[u'\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e8\u05d4', u"\u05e6'\u05d5\u05e4 \u05e6'\u05d5\u05e4"]
```

Comment: Using pure tk, fails on both on linux with tk 8.6.1, fails on Windows 7-64 with activestate tk 8.6.4.

Comment: Have you considered using \u05d9 instead of the ascii ' ?  Works better.

Comment: @Brad Lanam, \u05d9 is not ' (apostrophe), but a י (Hebrew letter yod), might look the same on some fonts but isn't (and especially in the listbox font doesn't even look the same at all). Also, this is Hebrew writing, so it comes out very wrong. The apostrophe code is \u0027 but of course this is what's already there (python's string repr just prints it out as the ascii equivalent)

Comment: Got it (don't know hebrew).
Essentially, on windows, there is some windows helper code (that apparently the `text` widget is using) that converts the display of the hebrew characters.   There has been some work done on Arabic character sets (search site:wiki.tcl.tk arabic) that handles the right-to-left-ness.  Tk doesn't handle right-to-left languages, so it will be up to you to fix it.

Comment: @Brad Lanam, thanks for trying to help. I found a solution without fixing Tk (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by setting font in the listbox

```
self.r_list = Listbox(self.frame, selectmode='multiple', exportselection=0, font=('Tahoma', 8))
```

It's not just the Tahoma font that works, I guess it's mostly an issue of the default font.